# Tornado, Django, and push notifications

Tags: javascript, django, html, push-notification, tornado

I've searched Stack overflow and all I can find is how to use Tornado as a HTTP server.

Now, my question is how do I start doing push notifications using the system?

Let me give you some context...

#### The database

I have a database on some server far away that I know nothing about, other than its a postgreSQL database and a piece of software on that server updates the database every so often ( maybe every couple of seconds, to couple of days).

#### Currently

I Have a django app that displays these database rows. it gets these database rows from a different app - an app called api -  using an ajax call every 5 seconds. As we all know this method is wasteful.

#### What I'd like to do

Well I'll bullet point it:

1. I'd like my Django app to stay the same in structure
2. The Django app will contain in its view JS code for connecting to a separate server.
3. this separate server will check the database for changes every 60 seconds. If the      database has changed, then notify the clients with a message, such as "new data available"

Hopefully thats not too vague.

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the [django-websocket-redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package suits my needs which are very much comparable to yours as it can easily be implemented on top of your existing project.

Mind that there are a few dependencies (UWGSI and Redis, primarily) and I've had to switch to a Linux development environment to get everything to work properly.